# Checking user input with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex so I hope that there is an easy problem to spot in this. Basically I'm trying to check if user input matches a word or phrase containing letters or numbers.
    `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)\s*`
Hope it's not too messy, all help is very much appreciated.
It works for a phrase like "the man is a" but not for "the man is a dog" which puzzles me.

Comment: Maybe you should simplify and simply use:  `([\w\s]+)`

Comment: Great resource here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work for both of your phrases and capture `the` both times, as your regex won't evaluate your second alternation, as the first one (`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`) will match every time (see [here](http://regex101.com/r/aM1rT7)).

If all you want to do is  match `a word or phrase containing letters or numbers` I'd use

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+
```

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bV2hT4)

I won't use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, as `\w` matches on `_` in many regex-engines, too.

Explanation:

```
(?:           #start of non-capturing group
  [a-zA-Z0-9] #character class matching one of a-z, A-Z and 0-9
  +           #between one and unlimited times
  \s?         #optional whitespace (includes tabs newlines)
)             #end of non-capturing group
```

Comment: What the ":" after the ? mark used for in this Regex Basti? I always have a tough time with Regexs as well.

Comment: @AlvinBunk `()` is a usual [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), while `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, so to only group tokens and not capture them.

Comment: Great, I think this answers the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check for letters or numbers, you can simply do:

```
String regex = "([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])+";
```